# Relationship in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My situation is i have four tables Patient, Receipt, Clinic and Laboratory.

```
 CREATE DATABASE TestHosp

 GO
 USE TestHosp
 GO
```

Information about patient

```
 CREATE TABLE Patient
 (Id INT Not NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
 FirestName VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 LastName VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
 Birthday DATETIME)

 CREATE TABLE Clinic
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
ClinicName VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
Price DECIMAL(8,2))

CREATE TABLE Laboratory
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
LaboratoryName VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
Price DECIMAL (8,2))
```

Note that the receipt contains a receipt number, One receipt belongs to one laboratory, One receipt belongs to one clinic i want do relation without create two column FK_Laboratory_ID and FK_Clinic_ID
and one number for all receipt any way to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
PatientID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Patient_ID] FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES Patient(Id),
DATE DATETIME,
Paid DECIMAL(8,2))
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it more readable?

Comment: Price makes no sense in Clinic and Laboratory. There will be multipel prices eventually for both, it is realted data not something that should be stored with the clinic or lab.

And fix the typo in your firstname field or it will annoy you for years.

Comment: OH and ID is a horrible name for an ID field. When you get into complex joins and reporting whcih you will with this type of data, it will be miserable to use (you'll be aliasising all over the palce when you don't need to with a proper naming convention. IDs should be named tablenameID and FKs should have the same name as the PK wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database design does not look good at all. If you could elaborate on design requirements, your schema can be very well improved.

To answer your question,

Patient (**Id**, FirstName, LastName, Birthday)

Clinic (**Id**, Name, Price)

Laboratory (**Id**, Name, Price)

Split your Receipt table into,

Clinic_Receipt (**Id**, *PatientId*, *ClinicId*)

Laboratory_Receipt (**Id**, *PatientId*, *LaboratoryId*)

```
     //Create Unique Ids for Receipts

     public int CreatId()
     {
         TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));

         return (int) t.TotalSeconds;
     }
```

Comment: @Rahul i know this issue but i want one number of receipt

Comment: @Said what do you mean by one number of receipt?

Comment: @Rahul Unique number of all receipt if i create two tables i have two id of receipt.

Comment: @Said Well you can insert unique receipt Ids so that there is no clash.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood your model, it is one-to-many. One receipt belongs to one laborary or clinic, but clinic can have more receipt. So it can be made similary as patients foreign key...

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
PatientID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Patient_ID] FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES Patient(Id),
ClinicID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clinic_ID] FOREIGN KEY (ClinicID) REFERENCES Clinic(Id),
LaboratoryID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Laboratory_ID] FOREIGN KEY (LaboratoryID) REFERENCES Laboratory(Id),
DATE DATETIME,
Paid DECIMAL(8,2))
```

Comment: Table is not normalized. Receipt can belong to either clinic or laboratory. So have clinic and laboratory in the same table will lead to null values.

Correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option (I did't edit my previous answer so that votes can be assigned to a better solution for you).

You can create a generalization as follows. However you will need more JOINs. There will be alwas 1 `Receipt` row and then 1 `Receipt_Laboratory` or 1 `Receipt_Clinic` with a corrensponding reference to either `Laboratory` or `Clinic`.

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
PatientID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Patient_ID] FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES Patient(Id),
DATE DATETIME,
Paid DECIMAL(8,2))

CREATE TABLE Receipt_Laboratory
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
LaboratoryID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Laboratory_ID] FOREIGN KEY (LaboratoryID) REFERENCES Laboratory(Id),
ReceiptID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Receipt_ID] FOREIGN KEY (ReceiptID) REFERENCES Receipt(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Receipt_Clinic
(Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
ClinicID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Clinic_ID] FOREIGN KEY (ClinicID) REFERENCES Clinic(Id),
ReceiptID INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Receipt_ID] FOREIGN KEY (ReceiptID) REFERENCES Receipt(Id))
```